# print reverse of a string

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I am writing a program which prints the reverse of a string in a textfield, taking input text from the other textfield.  When I press enter after entering text into one textfield the result(reverse) should be dispalyed in the other text field.

I have tried like this, but am getting weird results.

.h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface reverseVC : UIViewController {

    UITextField *textEntered;
    UITextField *textDisplay;

}
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UITextField *textDisplay;
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UITextField *textEntered;

- (NSMutableArray*) stringReverse;
- (IBAction) enter;

@end
```

.m file

```
- (NSMutableArray *) stringReverse
{

    NSString *value = textEntered.text;
    NSArray *tempArray = [[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:value,nil] autorelease];

    NSMutableArray *arr = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];


    for (int i=[tempArray count]-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        [arr addObject:[tempArray objectAtIndex:i]];
        NSLog(@"the object is:%c",arr);
    }

    return arr;
}
-(IBAction)enter
{
   textDisplay.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",[self stringReverse]];
}
```

Earlier got warnings like SIG_ABT and EXE_BAD_ACCESS before placing nil and autorelease in array initialisations. Now the warnings are solved but results undesiredly.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: you forgot to add `@synthesize` for your properties

Comment: `%c` is not the correct format string for `NSMutableArray`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this

```
NSString *str=textEntered.text;//
    NSMutableArray *temp=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for(int i=0;i<[str length];i++)
    {
        [temp addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",[str characterAtIndex:i]]];
    }
    temp = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[temp reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects]];
    NSString *reverseString=@"";
    for(int i=0;i<[temp count];i++)
    {
        reverseString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",reverseString,[temp objectAtIndex:i]];
    }
    NSLog(@"%@",reverseString);
```

Comment: tnx ishu for the answer and helping me know abt new concept "reverseObjectEnumerator" as i am new to iphone programming

Answer (score 9):

You insert the NSString object in your array. Its count is 1. You have to go from the end of the string to the beginning and append the character to a new string. You ca do it like this:

```
-(NSString*)reverseString:(NSString*)string {
    NSMutableString *reversedString;
    int length = [string length];
    reversedString = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:length];

    while (length--) {
            [reversedString appendFormat:@"%C", [string characterAtIndex:length]];
    }

    return reversedString;
}
```

Comment: pierre tnx for the reply.i would try in your approach too.keep helping me in future too

Answer (score 5):

Another way to reverse strings is to use the reverse string enumerator.

```
- (NSString *)reverseString:(NSString *)string {
    NSMutableString *reversedString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    NSRange fullRange = [string rangeOfString:string];
    NSStringEnumerationOptions enumerationOptions = (NSStringEnumerationReverse | NSStringEnumerationByComposedCharacterSequences);
    [string enumerateSubstringsInRange:fullRange options:enumerationOptions usingBlock:^(NSString *substring, NSRange substringRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL *stop) {
        [reversedString appendString:substring];
    }];
    return reversedString;
}
```

Comment: tnx anurag,helping me to learn new approaches and in that coarse i am getting to know new concepts.tnx alot guys......

Answer (score 0):

I revers my strings with a few lines of code. Rather late, but just putting it out there :)

```
- (NSString*) reverseMyString:(NSString*)theString
{
    NSString *final = @"";
    for(int i = theString.length-1; i>=0; i--)
        final = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%c", final, [theString characterAtIndex:i]];
    return final;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *str = @"hello";
int length = [str length];

NSLog(@"%d",length);

NSMutableString *rev = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithCapacity:[str length]];
while (length > 0) {
    --length;
    [rev appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", [str characterAtIndex:length]]];
}

NSLog(@"%@", rev);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `characterAtIndex` doesn't work well with non-ascii characters.

```
- (NSString *)reverseMyString:(NSString *)string {
    NSString *output = [[NSString alloc] init];
    for(int i = string.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
        output = [output stringByAppendingString:[string substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, 1)]];
    }

    return output;
}
```