# Take part of string in-between symbols?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa

I would like to be able to take the numbers lying behind the ` symbol and in front of any character that is non-numerical and convert it into a integer.

Ex.

```
Original String: 2*3*(123`)
Result:          123

Original String: 4`12
Result:          4
```

Thanks,
Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regular expressions. You can find all the occurrences like this:

```
NSString *mystring = @"123(12`)456+1093`";
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"([0-9]+)`" options:0 error:nil];
NSArray *matches = [regex matchesInString:mystring options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, mystring.length)];
for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [mystring substringWithRange:[match rangeAtIndex:1]]);
}
    // 12 and 1093
```

If you only need one occurrence, then replace the for loop with the following:

```
if (matches.count>0) {
    NSTextCheckingResult *match = [matches objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"%@", [mystring substringWithRange:[match rangeAtIndex:1]]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There can be better way to do this, Quickly i could come up with this,

```
NSString *mystring = @"123(12`)";
NSString *neededString = nil;
NSScanner *scanner =[NSScanner scannerWithString:mystring];
[scanner scanUpToString:@"`" intoString:&neededString];
neededString = [self reverseString:neededString];
NSLog(@"%@",[self reverseString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[neededString intValue]]]);
```

To reverse a string you can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4989834/641062)

Comment: works just as expected, except when there are multiple ones :P Now I just have understand it!